# font-family option in summernote not working

Tags: summernote

fontfamily option is not working in summernote
I tried

```
$("#divCalltoactiontitle").summernote({
        toolbar: [

            ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']], 
        ],
        fontNames: [
    'Serif', 'Sans', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Courier',
    'Courier New', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Helvetica', 'Impact', 'Lucida Grande',
    'Sacramento'
        ],

    } );
```

Answer (score 12):

It seems that you missed `fontname` on your toolbar settings. `fontNames` options is just setup font items.

```
toolbar: [
  ['fontname', ['fontname']
]
```

http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#custom-fontnames

For more about toolbar settings, please refer to default toolbar settings.

toolbar settings:
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/develop/src/js/bs3/settings.js#L67

fontNames settings:
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/develop/src/js/bs3/settings.js#L112

Answer (score 5):

`fontNames` option is to tell Summernote what to display in *fontFamily dropdown*.

> However, Summernote tests font in fontNames before adding them to
>   dropdown. This is problem while using web fonts. It’s not easy picking
>   up nice time to check availabilities of web fonts. You can define a
>   list for web fonts to be ignored with `fontNamesIgnoreCheck`.

Ref: http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#initialization-options

So, you probably need to add `fontNamesIgnoreCheck` option, too.

```
fontNames: [ 'Serif', 'Sans', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Courier', 'Courier New', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Helvetica', 'Impact', 'Lucida Grande', 'Sacramento'],
fontNamesIgnoreCheck: [ 'Serif', 'Sans', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Courier', 'Courier New', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Helvetica', 'Impact', 'Lucida Grande', 'Sacramento'],
```

Summernote also checks current font-family and font-size of your browser to initialize default font-family and font-size.

It is usually found in `body` style. If you set style of `body` as:

```
body {
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

Summernote will show `Helvetica Neue` and `16px` as default font-style and default font-size respectively.